# Is there a way to change the draw order in WPF

Tags: wpf, draw, stackpanel

Is there a way to change the draw order of Controls in a StackPanel without changing the actual ordering of these controls in the StackPanel?

The reason I ask is that we have a button bar with margin 0 between the buttons. The active button grows (ie margin set to -10) overlapping the neighbouring buttons. The problem here is that the right button is drawn later and thus is drawn on top instead of the active button.

I'm afraid I will need to make a custom control that is grid based..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of changing the draw order, just set the [Panel.ZIndex attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx).